# Проблемы с подключением к MySql 8, через Intellij Idea

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

После обновления jdbc драйвера в Intellij Idea, выскакивает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать разные драйвера, но ничего не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-нибудь знает решение, плиз хелп.

Comment: Кликните на `view` и покажите.

Comment: MySQL на localhost точно запущен?

Answer (score 0):

После инициализации каталога данных, и вы запустили сервер, выполните несколько простых тестов, чтобы убедиться, что он работает удовлетворительно. В этом разделе предполагается, что ваше текущее местоположение является установочным каталогом MySQL и что у него есть подкаталог bin, содержащий программы MySQL, используемые здесь. Если это неверно, соответствующим образом отредактируйте имена путей команд.

Кроме того, добавьте каталог bin в настройку переменной среды PATH. Это позволяет вашей командной оболочке (командному интерпретатору) правильно находить программы MySQL, чтобы вы могли запускать программу, введя только ее имя, а не его имя пути. См. Раздел 4.2.10 «Настройка переменных среды».

Используйте mysqladmin для проверки работы сервера. Следующие команды предоставляют простые тесты для проверки того, работает ли сервер и отвечает на соединения:

```
C:>bin\mysqladmin version
C:>bin\mysqladmin variables
```

Если вы не можете подключиться к серверу, укажите параметр -u root для подключения с правами root. Если вы уже назначили пароль для учетной записи root, вам также необходимо указать -p в командной строке и ввести пароль при появлении запроса. Например:

```
C:>bin\mysqladmin -u root -p version
Введите пароль: (введите здесь пароль root)
```